# Creating larger repeated sequence int[] from smaller int[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, integer, sequence

I am wondering if there is a way to create a larger int[] as repeated sequence of smaller int[].

For example,
a = {1, 2, 3}

I want to create b = int[9] so that:
b = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}

Is there a way to quickly populate b from having a and knowing how many time you want the sequence to repeat? (in this case 3)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a new array which is bigger than the original one times number of the sequences.
In your example the sequence number will be 3.
Your new array could be defined in a following way:

```
int[] b = new int[sequenceNumber * a.length];
```

Then, you need to re-write the numbers from array **a** to array **b** (times number of sequences). For example:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        b[i] = a[i % a.length];
    }
```